# How to write multiple log files for different Spring Batch Job?

Tags: spring-batch, spring-logback

I have developed a Spring Batch project that including multiple jobs.

My purpose is writing these job's log into separated files. For example, when **Job#1** is launched, all events are logged to **job_1.log**, when **Job#2** is launched, its events are logged to **job_2.log** and so on.

In my job configuration, I have used:

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Job1.class);
```

And I also try to configure logback.xml following the direction from this [link](https://www.mkyong.com/logging/logback-different-log-file-for-each-thread/) .
However, I do not know how to put MDC in Spring Batch (`MDC .put("logFileName", "Job1"`);

Are there better way for my problem when using Spring Batch?

Comment: Do you package all your jobs in the same jar? How do you run each job?

Comment: all my jobs are in the same jar. and I run them using JobLauncher by adding particular job and job parameters. The solution of Sabir Khan might work but I think it's not the best because If I have 10 jobs, I must have 10 loggers and 10 appenders in my logback. Are there any dynamic solutions? @Mahmoud Ben Hassine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have achieved this using log back & solution has nothing to do with Spring Batch but Spring Boot.

First I defined separate Loggers for each job in logback configuration file like below,

`

```
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml" />

<property name="LOG_PATH" value="${LOG_DIR}" />

<timestamp key="timestamp-by-second" datePattern="yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss" />

<appender name="Console-Appender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout>
        <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger{10} [%file:%line] %msg%n
        </pattern>
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="Job1"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_PATH}/Job1.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_PATH}/Job1.%i.log
        </fileNamePattern>
        <minIndex>1</minIndex>
        <maxIndex>600</maxIndex>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <triggeringPolicy
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger{10} [%file:%line] %msg%n
        </pattern>
        <outputPatternAsHeader>true</outputPatternAsHeader>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="Job2"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_PATH}/Job2.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_PATH}/Job2.%i.log
        </fileNamePattern>
        <minIndex>1</minIndex>
        <maxIndex>600</maxIndex>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <triggeringPolicy
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger{10} [%file:%line] %msg%n
        </pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="Job1Logger" level="info" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="Job1" />
</logger>

<logger name="Job2erLogger" level="info" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="Job2" />
</logger>

<root>
    <appender-ref ref="Console-Appender" />
</root>
```

`

then instead of - `private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Job1.class);` , you need to do , `private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("Job1Logger")`

Comment: It's worked perfectly. However, what is the LOG_DIR in <property name="LOG_PATH" value="${LOG_DIR}" /> ? How can I set dynamic path here? Ex:   Job 1 in folder 1 and Job 2 in folder 2. Or with a particular job, I must add 1 more property?

Comment: Sorry , forgot to mention that. `LOG_DIR` is base log directory and is an OS environment variable. You can also use something like - `<property name="LOG_PATH" value="" />`  to set `LOG_PATH` in xml itself.

Comment: So, If I want 5 different paths for 5 jobs, I must to set 5 properties for LOG_PATH?

Comment: I would say , try it out and see what works. I am not sure but I think defining `LOG_PATH` is mandatory. If you don't have a common base directory for all different logs, I don't think defining five base directories is a good idea ...just try specifing full path in `appender` tags.Defining base directory makes sense if there is a portion of path which is common otherwise not.

Comment: That would work perfectly but I have a question what if we have a number of classes used by both jobs, and they have their own logger but logically their log must be in the same file as the job who used the class, i don't know if my idea is clear, @SabirKhan what do you think do you have any suggestions I would be grateful

Comment: @iamamd: A logger can always be passed to a class in constructor or a class can have multiple loggers or a Logger instance can be passed to a Java method. A Logger is simply a Java Object and which logger to be used to log which message is something that a programmer has to decide.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This makes my life easier

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved using any log framework. In your case it is logback.

First in spring boot use below properties in your application.yml

```
logging:
  level:
    ROOT: DEBUG
  file: batch-job{job-name}.log
```

Note here job-name is a dynamic variable need to be passed at run time.

We can achieve it using MDC class of any log framework.

Just clear the MDC at the start of the job and set the new value.

```
MDC.put("job-name", "Job1");
```

For detailed code please see below post.

https://www.baeldung.com/mdc-in-log4j-2-logback

Now the catch is if you are scheduling the job at certain cron schedule then there might be a chance both jobs run at same time. In this case we need to make sure we create a new thread to run each job using Executor framework.