# Spring batch create a new log file per batch

Tags: spring, logging, spring-batch

I need to create a new log file per each batch i.e batch 1 will have log abc1.log, batch 2 will log abc2.log ...

In one of the writers we are calling one bean which is singleton we would like the logs from that bean be in the same as above. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write multiple log files for different Spring Batch Job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59280719/how-to-write-multiple-log-files-for-different-spring-batch-job)

Comment: This does not resolve my issue as I run the same job over and over. In addition the singleton has to access the correct logger. I was wondering if there is away to create a jobscope logger